# Java | While (boolean1 && boolean2)

Tags: java

hice un código que solicita lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realicé mi código y todo debería estar bien:

```
private static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(("##.00"));
private static Random r = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<String> files = new LinkedList<>();
    String[] filetype = {".exa", ".doc", ".ppt", ".xls", ".txt", ".pdf", ".icl"};

    int totalfiles = 0;
    int[] totalfiletype = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int tpages = 0;
    int tKbs = 0;
    double tMbs = 0;

    int cont = 0;
    boolean follow = true;
    boolean receive = true;
    while (follow && receive) {
            cont++;

            int randtype = r.nextInt(filetype.length);
            int randsize = r.nextInt(48001) + 2000;
            int randpages = r.nextInt(81) + 10;

            files.offer("Archivo" + String.format("%03d", cont) + filetype[randtype] + "     " + String.format("%2s", randpages) + "          " + String.format("%5s", randsize) + "Kb       " + String.format("%3s", df.format(((double) (randsize) / 1024)) + "Mb"));
            System.out.println("\nSe ha añadido un archivo nuevo, Cola actual: \n");
            System.out.println("Archivo        Num.Págs.     Tamaño Kb     Tamaño MB\n");
            printqueue(files);
            System.out.println();

            tpages += randpages;
            tKbs += randsize;
            tMbs += ((double) (randsize) / 1024);
            totalfiles++;

                if (filetype[randtype] == ".exa") {
                    totalfiletype[0]++;
                } else if (filetype[randtype] == ".doc") {
                    totalfiletype[1]++;
                } else if (filetype[randtype] == ".ppt") {
                    totalfiletype[2]++;
                } else if (filetype[randtype] == ".xls") {
                    totalfiletype[3]++;
                } else if (filetype[randtype] == ".txt") {
                    totalfiletype[4]++;
                } else if (filetype[randtype] == ".pdf") {
                    totalfiletype[5]++;
                } else if (filetype[randtype] == ".icl") {
                    totalfiletype[6]++;
                }

                if (cont > 20 && filetype[randtype] == ".icl") {
                    receive = false;
                    System.out.println("SE HA DETECTADO UN ARCHIVO '.icl'. PROCESO DE RECIBDO FINALIZADO");
                }

                if (cont >= 15) {
                    System.out.println("-".repeat(200) + "\n");

                    System.out.println("Impresión: ");
                    System.out.println("Archivo        Num.Págs.     Tamaño Kb     Tamaño MB");
                    System.out.println(files.peek());
                    files.remove();

                    System.out.println("\n Cola actual: \n");
                    System.out.println("Archivo        Num.Págs.     Tamaño Kb     Tamaño MB\n");
                    printqueue(files);
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();

                    if (files.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("No hay más archivos en la cola: ");
                        follow = false;
                    }
                }
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Total de archivos: " + totalfiles);
    System.out.println("Total de archivos '.exa': " + totalfiletype[0]);
    System.out.println("Total de archivos '.doc': " + totalfiletype[1]);
    System.out.println("Total de archivos '.ppt': " + totalfiletype[2]);
    System.out.println("Total de archivos '.xls': " + totalfiletype[3]);
    System.out.println("Total de archivos '.txt': " + totalfiletype[4]);
    System.out.println("Total de archivos '.pdf': " + totalfiletype[5]);
    System.out.println("Total de archivos '.icl': " + totalfiletype[6]);
    System.out.println("Total de páginas:       " + tpages);
    System.out.println("Total de Kbs:           " + tKbs);
    System.out.println("Total de Mbs:           " + tMbs);

}

public static void printqueue (Queue <String> queue) {
    for (String e : queue)
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

Pero tengo un problema: No sé si es posible hacer un while con dos condiciones booleanas:

```
boolean follow = true;
    boolean receive = true;
    while (follow && receive) {
     /*
     /
     /
     /
      */if (condicion) receive == false;
      
        if (condicion2) follow = false;
    }
```

Osea, declarar el segundo booleano (received) en "false" pero continuar con el ciclo hasta que el otro (follow) se declare "false".

Lo que trato de hacer con lo anterior es que, para "receive" va a estar generando elementos a la cola, pero cuando llegue a cierta cantidad y se tope con cierto "elemento", "receive" se vuelva "false", pero aún continuaría el bucle para que se esté vaciando la cola hasta que esta no contenga más elementos.

Al imprimir la consola, aunque ya haya finalizado el bucle, aún quedan elementos que deberían eliminarse.

Entonces, ¿Es posible hacer un ciclo while que contenga a dos booleanos? Si es así, ¿Se puede priorizar un booleano para que se "apague" el menos priorizado y continúe el otro hasta que finalmente finalice el bucle?

¿O hay otra forma de corregir mi error? Por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `while(follow && received)` hará que el bucle se ejecute solo mientras ***AMBOS*** sean true... `while(follow || received)` hará que el bucle se ejecute mientras ***ALGUNO*** sea true. La verdad es que la explicación que has puesto es un poco liosa, pero usar dos booleanos en una condición no es nada *raro*!

Comment: Ahora sí comprendí, muchas gracias.